# Your advice on Cloud Hosting

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I would like run my website (.NET 4 + MS SQL 2008) on the Cloud.

What I need is:

1. Managed Service for OS update and Security Paths.
2. DataBase MS SQL 2008 (ok even if shared with other website).
3. Reliable Technical support.

I looked at MS Azure, the service in quite flexible but their website does not provide cost and information about the Support (I also have no experience on deployment on that platform), I also evaluating MaximumAspESP (less scalable) but providing points above.

I would like ask you your advice on a serious Hosting Company (for cloud service).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used [Windows Azure Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/) and, to be honest, I'm not using Windows platforms at all, but I use several Amazon Web Services and I know that EC2 supports [Windows environments and SQL Server](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/).

Amazon EC2 is a very popular service, one of the (if not the) most used cloud environments. Huge companies relies on Amazon EC2. You'll find tons of tools, monitoring systems and services that interact with the Amazon platform.

RackSpace, the biggest Amazon competitor, also offers [Windows Virtual Servers](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/windows/). Their [Managed Service](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/faq/?page=msl) includes Windows servers as well.

Comment: However EC2 isn't a managed service - it's up to you to apply updates etc.

Comment: Is Amazon EC2 a Managed Solution? by Managed I means that security patches and general maintenance are done by amazon.

Comment: AFAIK, Amazon EC2 is not managed. I updated the answer to include also RackSpace, the biggest Amazon competitor. They are very famous for their customer support and they offer managed services.